# iphone application icon was blur when show on the itunes store

Tags: iphone

my icon was blur when show on the itunes Store but fine in iphone's locally appstore,my large icon format is:

pixel:512X512
format:png
dpi:72

can anybody point to me what is the reason of icon getting blur in itunes store since i have followed all the spec required by apple alr

Comment: try updating the project info and upload the 512 icon again. you might've uploaded the wrong file. Shouldn't the 512 image be a jpeg or tiff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your 512x512 icon should be a jpeg** though I can't imagine it being uploaded as iTunes Connect rejects other formats.

Resubmitting is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same problem today.  Reading the specs closer I realized they ask for at least a 24 bit .png file.  I had uploaded a 8 bit .png file to iTunes Connect.  I'm resubmitting today to test but I think this was my problem.